# UIPressesEvent pressType Select doesn't work in swift

Tags: swift, select, tvos

```
override open func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for press in presses {
        if press.type == .select {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .red // NOT BEING CALLED
        } else if press.type == .playPause {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        } else {
            self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, all the events work perfect but the `Select` event doesn't work.
Which supposed to be called when press ENTER key of the keyboard to detect tvOS surface click.

What's wrong with the above code.